# Javascript PHP template system

Tags: php, javascript, templates

**What I currently have:**

- index.php: Mainpage, showing topbar, navigation & placeholder for content
- navigation: uses javascript to load a php-file into the content-section from index.php if a link in the navigation is clicked; important: NO refresh of index.php

Is working fine right now. Also the url in the address bar is not being changed right now when clicking a link.

**What should be added:**

If a link in the navigation is clicked, javascript should still load a php-file but also should change the url in the address bar without refreshing the side.

Example:

- url: "www.example.com
- In navigation link "work" is clicked.
- work.php is loaded into the content-section of index.php
- url now: "www.example.com/work

Additionally if the user types www.example.com/work in the address bar index.php should load work.php without a link being clicked.

A good example to understand my issue with the url in the address bar is facebook. Hope I could clarify my problem so somebody is able to help me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the hashtag of a URL without refreshing the page (making another request). 
So when a navigation link is clicked you could change "www.example.com" to "www.example.com/#work" but you can't change it to "www.example.com/work" without reloading the page.

A hashtag can get set with javascript using window.location.hash

```
window.location.hash = "work";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to avoid hashtags, you can use the [HTML5 history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). This allows you to have the `/` in your pages using the `history.pushState()` and  `history.replaceState()` method.
There is also this [plugin](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) that you may find useful.